# AWS ELB Custom Headers Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

A strange behavior of ELB where custom HTTP headers are being dropped. I am currently using Nginx as the server with the following virtual host configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
        add_header Custom Test;
    }
}
```

By direct accessing the server using IP address, header "Custom: Test" can be found. But once this server resides behind an ELB. The custom header no longer show. May I know if this is an issue with my setup?

Comment: We ran into the same issue. Doesn't seem like there's any way around it.

Comment: Same here some headers are dropped, seems to be standard behaviour...

Comment: We are also running into this problem. Did anybody find a solution?

Comment: I have been experimenting with different custom headers. My observations so far suggest that headers containing an underscore (like `api_key: xxx`) get dropped by ELB, but headers without an underscore (like `apikey: xxx` or `apiKey: xxx` don't.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of response, I was able to consistently get the ELB to return all Response headers I tested - including those with _, however I will attempt to answer the question anyway.

From the documentation:

> When you use HTTP (layer 7) for both front-end and back-end connections, your load balancer parses the headers in the request and terminates the connection before sending the request to the back-end instances. [...]
>
> Not all HTTP extensions are supported in the load balancer. You may need to use a TCP listener if the load balancer is not able to terminate the request due to unexpected methods, response codes, or other non-standard HTTP 1.0/1.1 implementations.

This could be what results in the ELB dropping some headers. There isn't a definitive list of what it does or doesn't drop, but it implies anything non-RFC (`non-standard HTTP 1.0/1.1 implementations`)

If you need a custom header to be persisted where you're consistently observing it failing, then you can use a TCP LB instead. You'll lose things like X-Forwarded-For (but you can use the Proxy protocol to fetch this info) and Session Stickiness.

For the case of underscores - this is a little [discouraged](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) (at least with Nginx or other webservers) may have differing behaviour.